# How can I fetch and process PHP multiple $_POST records at once?

Tags: php, html, arrays, post

I'm designing a management interface where admins can modify members of a website all at once (bulk edit). We already have a single edit, but they want to be able to edit all the users at once and I wanted to do it so there is a single "Submit" button. The PHP code should then cycle through each record, look for changes and update as necessary. I know how to do everything but cycle through the records. I've tried creating an array, counting the posts records, I just haven't worked with arrays or mutli-dimensional arrays enough. Here's my existing code on the POST page:

```html
<?php  $i = 0;
  while($member_list = mysql_fetch_array($getmembers)){            
  ?>
              <tr style="vertical-align:top;">
                    <td><input type="text" name="userid[<?=$i?>]" readonly value="<?php echo $id; ?>" style="width:40px;"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="username[<?=$i?>]" value="<?php echo $member_list['mem_username']; ?>" onchange='changes=true;' style="width:90px;"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="firstname[<?=$i?>]" value="<?php echo $member_list['first_name']; ?>" onchange='changes=true;' style="width:90px;"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="lastname[<?=$i?>]" value="<?php echo $member_list['last_name']; ?>" onchange='changes=true;' style="width:90px;"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="email[<?=$i?>]" value="<?php echo $member_list['email']; ?>" onchange='changes=true;'></td>
                    <td><textarea name="notes[<?=$i?>]" cols="20" rows="2" onchange='changes=true;'><?php echo $member_list['admin_notes']; ?></textarea></td>
              </tr>
<?php  $i = $i + 1;  } ?>
```

And it posts to:

```
$user_records = array(count($_POST['userid'])); // create the array

foreach ($user_records as $value) {  // go through array
    $user_records[] = array( // Go through the array
        $username => $_POST['username'.$i],
        $firstname => $_POST['firstname'.$i],
        $lastname => $_POST['lastname'.$i],
        $email => $_POST['email'.$i],
        $notes => $_POST['notes'.$i],
        );

        echo $username . ' | ' . $firstname; //this line is for testing to display only
        // Then posting comparison occurs and is updates as needed  
}
```

So, in a nutshell - when I run the above example, I get 5 pipes (the amount of seperators for the 6 fields) but don't get any data and it doesn't cycle through any of the other records. I know I'm missing a few things, just can't put my head in gear to see it. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

NOTE: obviously I'll prevent SQL injection and clean up things in the final version. I'm just trying to figure out the logic here.

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST);` return ?

Comment: That returns all the data from the post. Do you want to see a sample of the data returned?

Comment: Obviously it does, post it here.

Comment: array(7) { ["submit"]=> string(8) "Save All" ["userid"]=> array(74) { [0]=> string(3) "201" [1]=> string(1) "9" [2]=> string(3) "192" [3]=> string(3) "185" [4]=> string(3) "215" [5]=> string(3) "171" [6]=> string(3) "159" [7]=> string(3) "204" [8]=> string(3) "164" [9]=> string(3) "156" [10]=> string(3) "147" [11]=> string(1) "2" [12]=> string(3) "208" [13]=> string(3) "202" [14]=> string(3) "209" [15]=> string(3) "178" [16]=> string(3) "203" [17]=> string(3) "177"

Comment: it would let me post very much... but that's a tiny sample

Answer (score 2):

You never defined `$i` inside your processing loop, so you're doing accessing unknown/undefined array keys.

Since you've defined explicit keys in your html via the `userid[$i]` stuff, your loop should be:

```
foreach($_POST['userid'] as $key => $userid) {
    $username = $_POST["username"][$key];
    $firstname = $_POST["firstname"][$key]; 
    etc...
```

Note how each of your username/firstname/etc... have themselves become arrays. It's not `username42`, it's `username[42]` to access that particular field.

Comment: Hmmm good point. Let me try working with that. Thank you. I'll you know the results.

Comment: That was it! PERFECT! Thank you SO MUCH Marc B!